# Do you capitalize Bill as in "Senator, please support this Bill"

Tags: orthography, capitalization

I was wondering if I need to capitalize it because my teacher highlighted it but without giving a reason.

Comment: Only if Bill is a person. And big contributor to the senator's campaign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When referring to a specific bill, the word "bill" has to be capitalized, i.e. ( [Acts Interpretation Amendment Bill 2011](http://parlinfo.aph.gov.au/parlInfo/search/summary/summary.w3p;adv%3Dyes;orderBy%3Dpriority,title;page%3D0;query%3DDataset_Phrase%3A%22billhome%22%20ParliamentNumber%3A%2243%22;resCount%3DDefault)).

However, when referring to any bills like for example:

> **Parliament passed 75 bills in the past three years**

The bill would not be [needed to be capitalized.](http://www.parliament.nsw.gov.au/prod/PARLMENT/hansArt.nsf/V3Key/LC20021121009)

Note how the Hon. Ian MacDonald moved for "these bills" to be read a second time.

Answer (score 4):

No.

The word "bill" should not be capitalized even in the following sentence:

Senator, please support amending Water Code bill.

Comment: This seems to be the majority position in the UK.  The [Guardian](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Atheguardian.com+bill&t=ffsb&ia=news) and [Times](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Athetimes.co.uk+bill&t=ffsb&ia=web) seem to follow this convention, while the [Telegraph](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Atelegraph.co.uk+bill&t=ffsb&ia=web) is inconsistent.